# How to append an element after specific child element using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to append a paragraph element after specific div class element.

I want to add a `p` element inside second `text` `div` class. I tried a solution but it's not working.

My solution it's not working. How can I insert this `p` element in second text div class using jquery ?

```js
$(".text:nth-child(2)").append("<p>Five</p>");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">
  <p>First</p>
</div>
<div class="text">
  <p>Second</p>
</div>
<div class="text">
  <p>Third</p>
</div>
<div class="text">
  <p>Fourth</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

nth-of-type this seems to work better

```js
$(".text:nth-of-type(2)").append("<p>Five</p>");
```

```css
.text { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">
  <p>First</p>
</div>
<div class="text">
  <p>Second</p>
</div>
<div class="text">
  <p>Third</p>
</div>
<div class="text">
  <p>Fourth</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.eq(n)](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```js
$(".text").eq(1).append("<p>Five</p>");
```

```css
.text {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">
  <p>First</p>
</div>
<div class="text">
  <p>Second</p>
</div>
<div class="text">
  <p>Third</p>
</div>
<div class="text">
  <p>Fourth</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.text:eq(1)').append("<p>Five</p>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you don't necessarily need jQuery, you can go with vanilla JS aswell.

```js
var el = [...document.getElementsByClassName("text")][1];
var p = document.createElement("p");
var t = document.createTextNode("Five");
el.appendChild(p.appendChild(t));
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <p>First</p>
</div>
<div class="text">
  <p>Second</p>
</div>
<div class="text">
  <p>Third</p>
</div>
<div class="text">
  <p>Fourth</p>
</div>
</div>
```